# putting a navigation bar in blackberry browser field

Tags: blackberry-webworks

How to put a navigation bar in the blackberry's browser field where we can put some buttons on the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Which phone/os are you intending to target with your app, there are several different approaches for different devices.

I personally like to recommend using a framework because they generally handle all your page navigation, loading/unloading document fragments, and make your life a lot easier as an app developer.

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is one framework you might want to take a look at.

[bbUI.js](https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js) is my personal favourite, although it's not "officially" supported, it's out proof-of-concept toolkit which provides a native look and feel.

Comment: Blackberry Os6 is the Os we are targetting.But im new to this area. could you put it in layman terms?

Answer (score 0):

I had found out the solution for my own Question.This may help somebody who are in need of that.

Putting a Navigation bar in blackberry is very simple.
Create a HorizanalFieldManager and instantiate it. Then add that object to the ScreenTitle.
That was worked for me.The Code is as follows.

```
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    ButtonField b1 = new ButtonField("back");
    ButtonField b2 = new ButtonField("refresh");

    hfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.ALICEBLUE));

    hfm.add(b1);
    hfm.add(b2);

    this.setTitle(hfm);
```